# burst with sugar and spice

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "burst with sugar and spice" as "be full of/explode with kindness and friendliness." Am I on the right track?

> The animal world seems to **burst with sugar and spice** these days. Evidence for cooperation and compassion among swimming, flying and walking creatures has captured public imagination. In the ocean, groupers, wrasse and eels form a multispecies team, working together to flush out and consume prey in bouts of collaborative hunting. In the sky, variegated fairy wrens and splendid fairy
> wrens recognize one another, form stable partnerships and jointly defend patches of eucalyptus scrubland. Among chickens, mother hens show empathetic distress when they see their chicks experience mild discomfort.

Source:  Scientific American September, 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have it correct.

The *only* place I have heard the phrase before is a [nursery rhyme:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Are_Little_Boys_Made_Of%3F)

> What are little boys made of?
> What are little boys made of?
> Snips, snails
> And puppy-dogs' tails
> That's what little boys are made of

> What are little girls made of?
> What are little girls made of?
> *Sugar and spice*
> *And everything nice*
> That's what little girls are made of

Obviously this is an unrealistic, sexist, and simplistic view of the difference between boys and girls. So the author of the article may be using it in a sarcastic way to mean "cute and loving things that really aren't as simple as that under the surface." Notice how they write at the beginning: "The animal world **seems** to burst with sugar and spice these days," setting up a "...but" to come later. Or they might be using the phrase at face value and nothing more.